# How do I can resolve the error regarding "installable set of packages in Laravel 5.5 ( laravelcollective/html couldn't be install. )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am working in laravel framework version 5.5. I am not able to install `laravelcollective/html`. via following command

```
composer require laravelcollective/html
```

I am getting the following errors

> ```
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> ```

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - laravelcollective/html v5.7 requires illuminate/view 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.2].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.7.1 requires illuminate/view 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.2].
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.40, required as 5.5.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.40].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html ^5.7 -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.7, v5.7.1].
```

> ```
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
> ```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the version of the html package you wish to install, otherwise it will attempt to install the latest version.

They version that package the same as the Laravel version it supports:

```
composer require laravelcollective/html:"5.5.*"
```

Comment: oh. i see. let me try this